# Quick Sorting in C++ is working intermittently

Tags: c++, sorting

What is wrong with my quick sorting algorithm? Sometimes it gives the right answer, sometimes it doesn't. Here's my code.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo(int*, int, int);
int main()
{
    int* a, n;
    cin >> n;
    a = new int[n];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << setw(3) << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "sorting array" << endl;
    foo(a, 0, n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
        cout << setw(3) << a[i];
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
void foo(int* a, int left, int right)
{
    int j = right;
    int i = left;
    int mid = (i + j) / 2;
    while (i < j)
    {
        while (a[i] < a[mid]) i++;
        while (a[j] > a[mid]) j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            swap(a[i], a[j]); i++; j--;
        }
    }
    if (i < right)
        foo(a, i, right);
    if (left < j) foo(a, left, j);
}
```

I've done some changed to my program  And it started working properly, the problem is that I don't understand why. I mentioned the changed in the code below. All the expected outputs matches the result.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo(int*, int, int);
int main()
{
    int* a, n;
    cin >> n;
    a = new int[n];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << setw(3) << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "sorting array" << endl;
    foo(a, 0, n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
        cout << setw(3) << a[i];
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
void foo(int* a, int left, int right)
{
    int j = right;
    int i = left;
    int mid = (a[right] + a[left]) / 2;//CHANGED LINE from mid=(i+j)/2
    while (i < j)
    {
        while (a[i] < mid) i++; //CHANGED LINE from a[i]<a[mid]
        while (a[j] > mid) j--; //CHANGED LINE from a[j]>a[mid]
        if (i <= j)
        {
            swap(a[i], a[j]); i++; j--;
        }
    }
    if (i < right)
        foo(a, i, right);
    if (left < j) foo(a, left, j);
}
```

Comment: please include an example input and output when it fails. (btw what about the non-gurus? No greetings to us?)

Comment: For testing, stop using random number. Instead figure out the most minimal "input" that cause the problem, and use those values hard-coded in the source. Then use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement (while monitoring variables and their values) to help you figure out when and where things go wrong. Also, to help with debugging don't try to put multiple statements on a single line, one statement per line makes things not only easier to read, understand and maintain, but also easier to debug.

Comment: don't use random numbers for testing and debugging. While testing and debugging you want reproducible results. Once it works with fixed input you can still use random numbers

Comment: Compared to me everyone is a guru, so as you my friend :D

Comment: The logic seems completely faulty. You are supposed to compare against some chosen pivot, yet you compare against a[mid] that can be  swapped during the process.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it worked with fixed, so I tried random ones and it showed that its not working properly

Comment: @Kaznov hmm, I think i got what youre saying, so how can i realize it in my code?

Comment: indeed it seems to work with fixed input: https://godbolt.org/z/zfv8hK3nj. Nevertheless using random input for testing is only useful when you record the sample input and output so you can repeat it later with hardcoding the faulty test cases

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thank's  a lot .

Comment: btw using a fixed seed is already much better than `time(NULL)`, because with a fixed seed you can easily repeat a test run. Or print the seed to the screen so you can use it later to repeat

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yeah I got your idea. I'll use it later in my other project, thank you for sharing with your experience.